# getting class of dynamically created parent element on keypress in dynamically created child input

Tags: jquery

I need to get id of dynamically created div when I hit a key in dynamically created input inside that div. I create them at same time after clicking button:

HTML:

```
<div id="known">
    <button id="create">Create</button>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create").on("click", function(){
        var num = 0;
        $("#known").append("<div id='unknown_" + num + "'><input type='text' class='get_id'/>");
        num++;
    });
});
```

This part is pretty obvious, but I can't solve problem when I have to attach function that gets id to something so it will work. I tried it like this:

```
$(".get_id").on("keypress", function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

but it won't work, because on load of page there doesn't exist any element with class get_id and if I attach it to the next higher element that exist its div known, so I can't use parent function to get that id, because it will give me id known. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them both in the same click function and put the num outside like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var num = 0;

$("#create").on("click", function(){

    $("#known").append("<div id='unknown_" + num + "'><input type='text' class='get_id'/></div>");
    num++;

    $(".get_id").on("keypress", function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this finally worked. 2 mins till accept.